# html5 ios native bridge for youtube autoplay, screentimeout and camera

Tags: ios, html, cordova, html5-video, trigger.io

I'm building an app which is going to have lots of a/b testing and a quick iteration cycle, so building native isn't an option for me.

The only 'features' that I need which can't be done in HTML5 are

1) autoplay youtube videos

2) keep the screen from turning off (timing out)

3) access the camera

I've already built the app in HTML5 with backbone.js, and I'm just now realizing the limitations of HTML5 in iOS.

What I'm not understanding is if in either PhoneGap or Trigger.io (or any of the other options) if I can autoplay a youtube video which is embedded in an html page. I am not looking for a video that takes-over the entire screen, I want to be able to play a segment of a video while keeping the rest of the app navigation.

Is this possible with any of these tools? Or does anybody have another recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers from Trigger.io's perspective:

1. Autoplay YouTube video: not sure this is possible - see below
2. Keep screen on: we don't support this yet, although would be happy to add it to our roadmap
3. Camera access: fully supported for capturing images and video

YouTube videos are embedded in pages using `iframes`: this wouldn't work well with Trigger.io in that we defer the loading of external web pages to iOS (see [Is the iframe tag allowed within a trigger.io page (not a tabs page)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454486/is-the-iframe-tag-allowed-within-a-trigger-io-page-not-a-tabs-page)).

There might be a way to embed a raw `object` which would work, but I haven't been able to find one to see about autoplaying.

Comment: Thanks for the response James, and best of luck with Trigger.io. I'll continue looking for the updates.

Answer (score 0):

For 1), since our v1.3.15 release it's possible to embed YouTube videos:

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-3-15